# How to print dependencies from llvm / clang (equivalent of gcc -MD)?

Tags: llvm, clang

Our build system is using gcc to generate source file's header dependencies to *.d files, when compiling:

```
gcc -MD -MF foo.d -c foo.o foo.cc
```

However, I can't figure out how to produce similar output with llvm clang.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's exactly the same:

```
clang -MD -MF foo.d -c foo.o foo.cc
```

An example:

```
$ cat example.c 
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  printf("Hello, world!\n");
  return 0;
}

$ clang -MD -MF example-clang.d -c -o example-clang.o example.c

$ gcc -MD -MF example-gcc.d -c -o example-gcc.o example.c

$ cat example-clang.d 
example-clang.o: example.c /usr/include/stdio.h /usr/include/_types.h \
  /usr/include/sys/_types.h /usr/include/sys/cdefs.h \
  /usr/include/machine/_types.h /usr/include/i386/_types.h \
  /usr/include/secure/_stdio.h /usr/include/secure/_common.h

$ cat example-gcc.d 
example-gcc.o: example.c /usr/include/stdio.h /usr/include/_types.h \
  /usr/include/sys/_types.h /usr/include/sys/cdefs.h \
  /usr/include/machine/_types.h /usr/include/i386/_types.h \
  /usr/include/secure/_stdio.h /usr/include/secure/_common.h

$ diff example-clang.d example-gcc.d 
1c1
< example-clang.o: example.c /usr/include/stdio.h /usr/include/_types.h \
---
> example-gcc.o: example.c /usr/include/stdio.h /usr/include/_types.h \
```

Comment: Doh. I tried it via "llvmc -clang", and just couldn't get it to work. Seems that it's better to just use clang directly. Thanks!

Comment: And where is this documented for clang?  I've not been able to find word one about the -MD, -MF and -MM options.

Comment: Clang mostly has the same options as gcc.  Mostly.

Comment: @CXJ It's listed if you run `clang --help`